# PHP SQL bind_param with STR_TO_Date error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm doing an update into the database but its not working using bind param but if I do it in a sql file and replace the ? to the actual values it works.

```
$sqlUpdate3 = $connection->prepare("UPDATE Users SET DateOfBirth = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(' ?, ?, ? ', '%d, %m, %Y')) WHERE UserName=?");
$sqlUpdate3->bind_param("ssss", $_POST["daySelect"], $_POST["monthSelect"], $_POST["yearSelect"], $_SESSION["username"]);
$sqlUpdate3->execute();
```

Comment: The server receives the query with '?, ?, ?' I'd guess as those question marks are within single quotes. Then STR_TO_DATE refuses to operate on that string mysql server side. Use one ? without quotes and pass the three $_POST variables concatenated (e.g. sprintf() call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question marks inside a string literal in SQL are not parameter placeholders, they're just literal question mark characters.

To make them parameters, you must put the question marks outside string delimiters:

```
$sqlUpdate3 = $connection->prepare("
  UPDATE Users SET DateOfBirth = 
  DATE(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(?, ', ', ?, ', ', ?), '%d, %m, %Y')) 
  WHERE UserName=?");
$sqlUpdate3->bind_param("ssss", $_POST["daySelect"], 
  $_POST["monthSelect"], $_POST["yearSelect"], $_SESSION["username"]);
```

However, I recommend to format the date in a MySQL-compatible YYYY-MM-DD format in PHP, then bind that as a single parameter.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setDate($_POST["year"], $_POST["month"], $_POST["day"]);
$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$sqlUpdate3 = $connection->prepare("
  UPDATE Users SET DateOfBirth = ?
  WHERE UserName=?");
$sqlUpdate3->bind_param("ss", $dateString, $_SESSION["username"]);
```